# How can I get the data from the specific place

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

```
import pandas as pd
import requests as req
import urllib.request
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = "https://www.pakwheels.com/used-cars/search/-/"
result = req.get(URL)
src = result.content
src
soup = BeautifulSoup('src','lxml')
soup
car_name = soup.find_all("<li>")
```

the data which i need to access is in li[image] as i trying to find all the li but when i print the car_name it gives no data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pure typographical error from your side in your code. 
In stead of
`soup = BeautifulSoup('src','lxml')`

It should be 
`soup = BeautifulSoup(src,'lxml')`

Also as suggested by @prophet in his answer, use `car_name = soup.find_all("li")`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
car_name = soup.find_all("<li>")
```

try

```
car_name = soup.find_all("li")
```

**UPD**
`find_all` method returns a list of web elements.
To see each car text (price) you can iterate over that list and get each element text.
Something like this:

```
car_names = soup.find_all("li")
for name in car_names:
    print(name.text)
```

Comment: how do I check if it actually retrived the data from li .

Comment: I am using print(car_name) this is the output I get [ ]

Comment: Let me know if this resolved your problem

Comment: No, It still doesn't give any output,